# Segmentation fault Error

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault error. 
Can anyone tell me why?

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

       char sumArrays(int * arr1[], int * arr2[], int length, int count){
       if(count == length){
           return ' ';
       }
       else{
          int sum = 0;
       sum =  *arr1[count] + *arr2[count];
       char ch = '            
       ch = ch + (char)sum;
       return ch + sumArrays(arr1, arr2, length, count+1);
    }
  }

int main(int argc, char * arr[]){
    int length = 6;
    printf("Enter the first row of 6 integers:");
    int * arr1 = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int * arr2 = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int counter = 0;
    int number = 0;
    while(counter < length){
       scanf("%d", &number);
       arr1[counter]=number;
       counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    printf("Enter the second row of 6 integers:");
    while(counter < length){
      scanf("%d", &number);
      arr2[counter] = number;
      counter++;
    }
    char sum = sumArrays(&arr1, &arr2, length, 1);
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);
    printf("Their sums are : %c ", sum);
    return 0;
  }
```

I am new to C and do not know much about the language. I was 
able to write the program in Java and get it working.
Any help is appreciated!

Thankyou!

Edit:
segmentation error is fixed but now it does not print the actual char of the sums....

Comment: Where does the debugger say that the fault occurs?

Comment: it doesn't. it happens after I input the 6 integers for each array.

Comment: Enter the first row of 6 integers:1 2 3 4 5 6
Enter the second row of 6 integers:1 2 3 4 5 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
this is what comes in the terminal. I'm sorry I'm very new to coding in C and using linux so I'm not sure how to use the debugger in general....

Comment: Maybe you should learn about `for(;;)` loops.

Comment: Remember that arrays are indexed from 0 in C.  It is odd that you are returning a `char` when you are summing `int` values.  Your function would be simpler if it took two `int *` arguments, and you changed your call to `char sum = sumArrays(arr1, arr2, length, 1);`, dropping the ampersands.

Comment: 0x080484c8 in sumArrays () is what happened when I use gdb for the program...

Comment: @user1998581: compile with `-g` to get line number info

Comment: yes I know they are indexed at 0. I had 0 in the original code but still got the same error so changed it to one and forgot to change it back. Also, I know about for(;;) loops, I just chose to use a while loop

Comment: @rburny my program compiles fine, it happens when my program runs

Answer (score 1):

This is another case of "&array doesn't make an array of pointers".

This is an array of pointers:

```
 int * arr1[]
```

This makes an pointer to an array of integers;

```
&arr1     // That is, one pointer to your array of integers.
```

So, when you access this for count > 0, the compiler tries to read a pointer value that you haven't given.

```
*arr1[count]
```

The fix is to remove a star here and there and the & at other places:

Remove `*`

```
   char sumArrays(int * arr1[], int * arr2[], int length, int count){
   sum =  *arr1[count] + *arr2[count];
```

remove &:

char sum = sumArrays(&arr1, &arr2, length, 1);

I personally would also change this:

```
int length = 6;
int * arr1 = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
int * arr2 = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
```

to:

```
const int length = 6;
int arr1[length];
int arr2[length];
```

and get rid fo the `free(arr1); free(arr2)` at the bottm. No need to allocate arrays until they get quite big, a few hundred integers is perfectly fine.

Comment: The reason I allocated is because in the terms of the problem I should be able to change the length to up to 1000 integers. Will try the fixes and get back, thank you

Comment: So, make it a fixed size of 1000, and use length to determine how many to actually use... ;)
Bear in mind that allocating on the stack is one instruction to make the space (a subtract on the stackpointer), to make space with malloc is a function call to a rather complex function, and free isnt that much better).

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
sum =  *arr1[count] + *arr2[count];
```

you are dereferencing second-level pointers in the wrong order. Correct one would be:

```
sum =  (*arr1)[count] + (*arr2)[count];
```

But the real answer is: you don't need to take an address of `arr1`. Change sumArrays declaration to:

```
char sumArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[], int length, int count)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I am still learning everything so I am still a little confused when to use pointers and when not to use pointers

Comment: The only thing not working now is it doesn't actually print the actual sums.... hmmm